# Best tool to use to measure non-standard label sizes for printing with MS Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, mail-merge, label

Is there a specific brand of ruler or system (such as Metric or American) that should be used when measuring the size of non-standard (read "cheap") labels when you want print a bunch of addresses on some labels using Microsoft Word 2007?

Answer (score 1):

All standard Avery label sizes work with Word, so I guess you can just measure your labels in inches and compare them to Avery's (see list [here](http://www.avery.com/avery-product-selector/ps?locale=en_US&int_id=quicklinks-productselector)).

Answer (score 0):

Almost all brands of labels, such as the office supply store house brands, will give the equivalent Avery label number somewhere on the package.  Then you can just pick that Avery number from the list in Word.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah I looked for something like this...I thought it would make sense that they would do that...